# ValueError: Layer "model_20" expects 3 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors. Inputs received: []. How to fix this

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, artificial-intelligence

Creating a machine learning model which will generate html code and css depending on the image passed. We are passing csv file which includes html path, css path and image for training the model but I am getting error *"ValueError: Layer "model_20" expects 3 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors. Inputs received: []."* How to fix this

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

# Load data from CSV
csv_file = 'data.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(csv_file)

# Define data directories (assuming images are in the same directory as the CSV file)
image_dir = os.path.dirname(csv_file)

data_train=data[data.html_path.isnull()==False]
# data_test=data[data.html_path.isnull()==True]

vocab_size = 1000

# Split the data into training and testing sets
train_data, test_data = train_test_split(data_train, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Extract data for training
train_image_paths = train_data['image_path'].tolist()
train_html_texts = train_data['html_path'].tolist()
train_css_texts = train_data['css_path'].tolist()

# Extract data for testing
test_image_paths = test_data['image_path'].tolist()
test_html_texts = test_data['html_path'].tolist()
test_css_texts = test_data['css_path'].tolist()

# Load and preprocess image data for training
train_images = []
for image_path in train_image_paths:
    img_path = os.path.join(image_dir, image_path)
    img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(img_path, target_size=image_size)
    img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
    img = tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input(img)
    train_images.append(img)

# Load and preprocess image data for testing
test_images = []
for image_path in test_image_paths:
    img_path = os.path.join(image_dir, image_path)
    img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(img_path, target_size=image_size)
    img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
    img = tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input(img)
    test_images.append(img)

# Tokenize HTML and CSS code for training
train_html_sequences = tokenizer(train_html_texts)
train_css_sequences = tokenizer(train_css_texts)

# Tokenize HTML and CSS code for testing
test_html_sequences = tokenizer(test_html_texts)
test_css_sequences = tokenizer(test_css_texts)

# Define input layers
image_input = keras.layers.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3), name='image_input')
html_input = keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_seq_length,), name='html_input')
css_input = keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_seq_length,), name='css_input')

# CNN for image feature extraction
cnn_model = keras.applications.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_tensor=image_input)
flatten_layer = layers.Flatten()(cnn_model.output)
image_features = layers.Dense(256, activation='relu', name='image_features')(flatten_layer)

# RNN for HTML code generation
html_embedding = layers.Embedding(vocab_size, 128)(html_input)
html_rnn = layers.LSTM(256, name='html_rnn')(html_embedding)
html_output = layers.Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax', name='html_output')(html_rnn)

# RNN for CSS code generation (similar to HTML)
css_embedding = layers.Embedding(vocab_size, 128)(css_input)
css_rnn = layers.LSTM(256, name='css_rnn')(css_embedding)
css_output = layers.Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax', name='css_output')(css_rnn)

# Combine image and code features
concatenated_features = layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([image_features, html_output, css_output])

# Final output layers for HTML and CSS
html_output_final = layers.Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax', name='html_output_final')(concatenated_features)
css_output_final = layers.Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax', name='css_output_final')(concatenated_features)

# Create the model
model = keras.Model(inputs=[image_input, html_input, css_input], outputs=[html_output_final, css_output_final])

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])


# Define the batch size and number of epochs
batch_size = 32
epochs = 10

# Define separate datasets for each input
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_images, train_html_sequences, train_css_sequences))
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(batch_size)

test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((test_images, test_html_sequences, test_css_sequences))
test_dataset = test_dataset.batch(batch_size)

# Train the model
model.fit(train_dataset, validation_data=test_dataset, epochs=epochs)
```

The structure of CSV file :

[image]

Comment: Would you provide your input data shapes (training, validation or testing) with summary of your model.

Comment: Well from first insight, it seems you need to pass a list into your fit function than only single dataset, like maybe a list of the three input data.